# php/jquery: Create Csv from form data without submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, csv, form-submit

I have a simple html form like below. I am using php and the site is hosted into a server. Users access it and submit their information. I want to save their data what they have given into their own pc (client pc) as a csv file regardless of network connectivity is lost or available.

```
<?php 

     error_reporting(0);
     require('commonVar.php');

     if(@$_POST)
     {
    $stdloggedid=$_POST['stdloggedid'];
    $stdloggedinBoard=$_POST['stdloggedinBoard'];
    $stdloggedinChest=$_POST['stdloggedinChest'];
    $stdloggedinName=$_POST['stdloggedinName'];  

    //file
    if(isset($_POST['csv_btn']))
    {

        // csv create 
            $answer_ids_str = '';
            $setdetail_str = '';
            $qs_id_str = '';

            foreach($setqs_id as $key=>$did)
            {

                if($_POST['answer_ids'.$did]!=''){

                    $answer_ids_str != "" && $answer_ids_str .= "|";
                    $setdetail_str != "" && $setdetail_str .= "|";
                    $qs_id_str != "" && $qs_id_str .= "|";

                    $answer_ids_str .= $_POST['answer_ids'.$did];
                    $setdetail_str .= $setdetail[$key];
                    $qs_id_str .= $did;
                }


            }

            $exam_type='it_vit';
            $set_id = $_POST['set_id'];
            $ans = $_POST['ans'];
            $filename="it_vit";
            header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
            $csv_filename = $stdloggedinName.'_'.$filename."_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time()).".csv";
            if (!file_exists('D:/result/')) {
                    mkdir('D:/result/', 0777, true);
            }

            $fd = fopen ('D:/result/'.$csv_filename, "w");

            $fileContent="qtype,qs_set_id,qs_detail_id,question_id,answer_ids,boardno,chestno,applicant_id,name,exam_date_time\n";
            $fileContent.= "".$exam_type.",".$setid.",".$ans.",".$stdloggedinBoard.",".$stdloggedinChest.",".$stdloggedid.",".$stdloggedinName."\n";
            $fileContent=str_replace("\n\n","\n",$fileContent);
            header("content-disposition: attachment;filename=$csv_filename");
            echo $fileContent;

            fputs($fd, $fileContent);

            fclose($fd);
            exit();
            // csv create end

    }else{
        // insert into db
    }

 }

?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> Assesment </title>


</head>

<body>

<div>
 <section class="content-header" style="background-color:#ED1C24;color:#fff;position:fixed;width:100%;z-index:1000;padding-bottom:7px;border-bootom:2px solid #ccc">
      <h1 style=" text-transform:uppercase;font-size:18px " >
       <span><img src="../images/nhdlogo.png" width="40" style="margin-right:15px"/></span>
       VIT Assesment Test

      </h1>
</section>

<!-- Main content -->
<section class="content" >
      <div>&nbsp;</div>
      <div>&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="row">
       <!-- <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>-->
        <!-- left column -->
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="box box-success">


                <form id="userform"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                     <input name="set_id" type="hidden" id="set_id" value="<?=$set_id?>">
                     <input name="ans" type="text" id="ans" value="">
                        <div class="box-header with-border" id="allqs">

                            <div class="col-lg-12 box-footer" id="sbtbtn">
                                     <input type="submit" name="csv_btn" id="csv_click" class="btn btn-primary" value="csv" /> 
                                    <input type="submit" name="sarticle" id="submit_click" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" /> &nbsp;**Click Submit If you answer to all the questions.

                            </div>

                        </div>
                </form>
             </div>
        </div>
     </div>
 </section>
```

In this code, I want to save the file in D drive of each user's PC. It works fine when the wifi connection is ok. But somehow if the connection is lost after appearing the form to user's Pc then how can i create and save csv when they press csv btn?

How can i do this?? In case of wifi connectivity is lost, When a user press submit button his browser says 'Server Not found'. If i use ajax and form.serilize() then how can I able to create and download csv file on local PC ??

Comment: I wouldnt rely on a user always having a D drive... Should just prompt the user to save the file and they determine location.

Comment: ok..That will do also. But download csv using ajax or not server calling is the main factor here.

Comment: I could give the proper answer to your question, but your's CSV content have more fields than your form. If you provide a fiddle with all fields in your form and the exact structure of CSV file, I can help you

Comment: @GabrielChiquini This is the simple jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/axgap2fz/

Here, set_id & ans are taken from form and exam_type is static value which is 'it_vit'.
there are four session data:
$stdloggedid=$_POST['stdloggedid'];
    $stdloggedinBoard=$_POST['stdloggedinBoard'];
    $stdloggedinChest=$_POST['stdloggedinChest'];
    $stdloggedinName=$_POST['stdloggedinName'];  

So, finally there will be total 7 col in only one row in generated csv like the following:
   exam_type | set_id | ans | stdloggedid | stdloggedinBoard | stdloggedinChest | stdloggedinName

Comment: My idea is do everything without calling the server, as you said. So, this can only be possible if you create hidden input fields in your form with your static fields. Can you update the fiddle?